# Issue using bluetooth on iPhone/iPod

Tags: iphone, bluetooth, multiplayer, gkpeerpickercontroller

I'm trying to set-up a bluetooth based communication between two iOS devices. 
Basically I'm trying to create a multiplayer game between two iPhones/iPods using bluetooth.

I'm using `GKPeerPickerController` to show the two options: *Online* or *Nearby Game*.

**Problem**: When I hit *Nearby* for the first time, nothing happens. I get the following log:

```
BTM: attaching to BTServer
2011-12-22 22:57:22.222 Plane Killer[144:707] <<< Picker >>> -[GKPeerPickerViewController _updatePicker:]: unhandled pending state: GKPeerPickerStateUnknown
```

Second time when I hit *Nearby*, I get the "alert" saying that my device is looking for other devices.

The funny thing is that I'm not able to find `GKPeerPickerStateUnknown` on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that the problem appears only when I add both `GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby` and `GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline`.

```
GKPeerPickerController *mPicker=[[GKPeerPickerController alloc] init];
mPicker.connectionTypesMask = GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby | GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeOnline;
```

I will fix it by changing my UI.
I will create my own buttons for playing online and nearby.